# Can't set the current date container in the main screen view

Tags: flutter

So, in this code i want to see the current date container home screen (main screen) then left of that container last 10 days container and right of that container upcoming 10 days container will be apear and i can scroll to see that. How can i do that ? in this code the left most container is apearing. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Date Scrolling',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DateScrollingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DateScrollingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Date Scrolling'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 21, // 10 past days, current day, and 10 upcoming days
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
              DateTime date = currentDate.add(Duration(days: index - 10));
              bool isCurrentDate = index == 10;

              return Container(
                width: 150, // Width of each date container
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: isCurrentDate ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '${date.day}/${date.month}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: isCurrentDate ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      isCurrentDate ? 'Today' : '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: isCurrentDate ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried centering in the main screen but i couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it using `ScrollController`

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(
    initialScrollOffset: 150*10, // 150 is your container width * first 10 days
    keepScrollOffset: true,
  );
```

and associate it with the list view:

```
ListView.builder(
controller: scrollerController,
....
)
```